# Disabling iOS scaling

Tags: javascript, html, browser, scalability

I have been suffering for a very long time to disable zooming with fingers, double clicks, etc. on iOS, so that it is cross-browser on all devices. Completely disable scaling on mobile phones.

I tried user-scalable=no in

BUT! it still works every other time and the double-click approximation works.

Comment: Move your answer into the question so it is more complete.

Comment: @stwissel Is my question not clear? How to disable the proximity feature on the phone on all devices (iOS, android) and on all browsers.

Comment: Now it’s clear. I wonder why you want to cripple an accessibility feature? Unless you are the only user of your app, it’s up to the user if they want to zoom or not. I would claim you can’t know. So the question is: what problem triggered the idea to limit your users choice of interaction